# How to access a different position of a database in Access from Visual Basic - ADODB Connection

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I am using the `ADODB` function to access a database in `Access` from `Visual Basi`c. The purpose is to access a specific query, copy the data from a cell and paste it in Excel. So far, I've been able to obtain the heading of the query, and the first row of data, but don't know the code needed the get the remaining information. This is what I've used:

`Dim Conjunto As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim conexionBD As New ADODB.Connection`

**To open the database:**

`conexionBD.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & BDatos`

The code that allows me to copy both the headings and the first row of data is:

```
For i = 1 to 10
   Cells(1,i).value = Conjunto.Fields(i).Name
   Cells(2,i).value = Conjunto.Fields(i)
Next i
```

Up until this moment the code works perfectly. I am so far accessing each value of the dataset (from the database in Access) both out of the headings (first line in the *for*) and the first row (second line). But I don't know how to get the information from the subsequent rows (the **"Fields"** function specifies an **"index"** which in this case doesn't let me use anything longer than the number of total values in each row (10)).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Show all your code - if you've got it working so far you must have an OpenRecordset call? After that you wrap your For loop in a `While not Conjunto.EOF` `Conjunto.MoveNext` and `Wend`. I'd put this in an answer but you've given us very little to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Headers
For i = 1 to 10
   Cells(1,i).value = Conjunto.Fields(i).Name
Next i

'Records
r=2
Do While Not Conjunto.EOF
    For i = 1 to 10
       Cells(r,i).value = Conjunto.Fields(i)
       r=r+1
    Next i
    Conjunto.MoveNext
Loop

'or:
Cells(2,1).CopyFromRecordset Conjunto
```